# PayPal Transactions API to recreate and reconcile with PayPal Financial Summary

Tags: paypal, transactions, finance, summary

I am trying to recreate and reconcile the Financial Summary per currency available to a merchant from their reports using PayPal APIs. I have successfully setup the Transactions API which has the transaction event codes, but these are not detailed enough to be able to map across to recreate the Financial Summary.

For example T0004 "ebay auction payment" in the API, can be both a Sale as well as a Purchase on the Financial Summary. What further details can I receive from PayPal APIs, to be able to ascertain the correct results?

Many Thanks

Gurpreet

Comment: What do you mean by "PayPal Transactions API" ?

Comment: http://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions

Answer (score 0):

The Transactions Search API isn't meant to be used for financial reconciliation purposes. It is not built for that purpose, nor are there any other APIs built for reconciliation purposes.

PayPal Reports (available in the merchant account, from the Reports tab) are suited to this purpose. Large merchants can also request access to an SFTP reporting service, for automated daily deliveries to a dropbox: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/#create-an-sftp-user-account

Comment: As a merchant if go to “Monthly Financial Summary Report” and choose a currency say “GBP” and generate a report.  I can click on the figure for “Sale Activity” and it will show a list of transactions included that sum up to that amount. I simply want to be able to recreate this list through an API.  I know of the Dropbox functionality and it is not suitable for my task.  Surely there must be a way to do this.

Comment: There is no API for this, the account interface should be used for reporting purposes. Results can be downloaded in csv format if you need something to import